# Customize WordPress output based on form inputs

Tags: php, wordpress, bots, decision-tree

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet containing a list of links and resources pertaining to a particular topic. I want to create a WordPress page where I ask the user a branching series of questions (i.e. "which topics are you interested in?") And depending on the answers to those questions, display only the links that are relevant to them.

I am a newbie when it comes to WordPress but I do have experience in programming (mostly in Python).

How could I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should inmerse a bit on wordpress development as programmer, i will explain a fast progress for learn it.. read this https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development and this https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress too.

Then when you check some videos for how to create your own template..

Do a CPT [ Custom Post Type ] who's called links of topic or something like, then you can create an "Archive-Topic-Links" (Very important for a wordpress developer [ https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png ] which files can you create before or after one) who gonna iterate over all of them.. look at this.. [ https://generatewp.com/post-type/ ] and try to learn about how to use a CMB2 for create inputs in your cpt is it a free version of ACF.

With this you will have a 50% of your proyect then should be learn how to categorize and much more... but when you reach this 50%.. the other will be easy.

Ah, try to don't use much plugins make your code.. and other tip wordpress isn't very friendly for multilanguage

I hope this improve to you, mate and other to start the wordpress development.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate PHP with google spreadsheet, I will use the google api https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php, in this way you can read all rows and integrate with php wordpress